# Laravel, Vuejs - Adding a template purchased from themeforest

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I installed laravel 5.6 and used a template i purchased from themeforest. I have all the css and js files in version1 folder (public/version1/app.min.css and public/version1/js/app.min.js). Then i modified the template as per blade rules and the website renders good. I want to use a javascript framework for frontend with this template for creating SPA applications so that i can view other pages without refreshing. I checked react, loved it however i see vue is good too with laravel.

I ran `php artisan preset vue` and `npm install && npm run dev`

Are there any other steps im missing? I have searched alot and couldn't find a single resource on how to use a template (purchased) with vue and laravel.

Any links to get me started would also help me. I have the links for creating crud with vue.

Comment: You need to make you componenets using this template in resources/assets/js folder where vue bootstrap and exaple component resides. And if you need to seprate both then use vue-cli to initiate frontend app which will consume your backend laravel apis

Comment: I strongly recommend that you see this tutorial or another, there are a lot that explain very well the steps to follow  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJ6PD_jBtU0

Comment: @MaruAmallo When i run npm run dev, there is bootstrap  code filled in app.css and app.js which disturbs the template layout. How to fix this?

Comment: mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
mix.styles([
       'public/version1/assets/css/app.min.css',
       'public/version1/assets/css/primary.css',
       'public/version1/assets/css/style.css'
   ], 'public/css/app.css');

Comment: That hos my laravel mix looks like now. Is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Srikanth Gopi Is difficult to explain that for many reasons, but the more important is that I have not your theme, but you can see this project https://github.com/Braunson/laravel-coreui-vue. I hope help you and maybe you can use that to learn how Vue works into Laravel. 
In my case i use Laravel as an api service and i make a Vue client. That work for me and is easier for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followed this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/theme-where-should-i-put-css-and-js) and made the following changes

I placed all the css files in resources/assets/css folder and all the js files in the public/js folder.

Updated the webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
mix.styles([
      'resources/assets/css/app.min.css',
      'resources/assets/css/primary.css',
      'resources/assets/css/style.css'
  ], 'public/css/app.css');
```

Now everything is compiled into public/css/app.css and the theme is rendered without any issues.